# How to update all product details using Google Content API for Shopping?

Tags: php, google-content-api

In the documentation for the Google Content API for Shopping, I found a section on updating products: [Inventory: set](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/inventory/set).

However, it only seems to update price, availability and quantity:

```
{
  "price": {
    "value": string,
    "currency": string
  },
  "availability": string,
  "salePrice": {
    "value": string,
    "currency": string
  },
  "salePriceEffectiveDate": string,
  "quantity": unsigned integer
}
```

How do I update the product name, product website link, product image link and all the details that can be inputted using the [Products: insert](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/products/insert) API call?

The Google Service library seems only to allow the update of price, availability and quantity. Does Google restrict updating the other data or have I not found the correct documentation?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the documentation is out of date and in parts incorrect. I have yet to find someone with dependable documentation so far. Maybe one day Google will go Pro and treat their documentation with more importance. People rely on this technology, but it's just an experiment to Google. That wouldn't be so bad if it wasn't absolutely required in today's market to compete.

I queried a google person yesterday who works around the api and she stated that they didn't know when it would be updated to what is current.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `products.insert` endpoint to also update products and products with the same `offerId` will be overwritten.

As I haven't tried it yet and the documentation seems not to explain this, I don't know whether the provided attributes will be merged with the existing ones, or whether you actually need to provide the full representation (because the new insert might be equivalent to a delete + insert).